# Infopath 2013 hide ribbons

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online, office-365, form

I published an infopath form to my list. I want to hide the edit ribbon as shown below.

[image: infopath form]

but unfortunately when I hide ribbon using Form Options in Infopath 2013, my Rich Text Field named as Body has been damaged. Please refer to image below.

[image: infopath form2]

Please help.

Comment: This is a difficult question without more details. You can style infopath forms using CSS and give your textbox a fixed with and height, maybe that will fix the issue.  http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/greg/archive/2005/06/07/Add-a-Custom-Style-Sheet-to-a-View.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this way around, using javascript you can show and hide ribbon on particular page.

1. Open your SharePoint master page
2. Locate this line: `<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">`
3. Change it to: `<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle" style="display:none">`
4. Now find the end of the “s4-ribbonrow” tag and add following block right after it:

   `<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages">     <script type="text/javascript">         document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";     </script> </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl`>
5. Save the new master page and publish it.

Comment: What is the need for the SecurityTrimmedControl here?

Comment: If you want to show it to current user having permissions defined in the PermissionString, then we can add  SecurityTrimmedControl else want to hide for all in that case no need.

Comment: Thabks @Anuja.. Ill try this and Ill get back to you. :))

Comment: This is a bit of a hack... but who cares, it's SharePoint right? :P

Comment: Is this applicable to sharepoint Online? :)